# Data not being displayed correct in table, JavaFx using SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx

I am attempting to display the data stored within my database (sqlite), I can retrieve the data but it displays its datatype before it! For example instead of displaying "1" it displays "IntegerProperty [Value: 1]"

[image]

Here is a picture of the database (the table called "Records"):
[image]

Here is a picture of the project structure:
[image]

Here is the controller class:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import db.dbConnection;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

public class mainController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<RecordData, String> ncol;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<RecordData, Double> pcol;

    @FXML
    private TextField artist;

    @FXML
    private TextField year;

    @FXML
    private TextField rating;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<RecordData, String> gcol;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<RecordData, String> acol;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<RecordData, Integer> idcol;

    @FXML
    private TextField price;

    @FXML
    private TextField name;

    @FXML
    private TextField genre;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<RecordData, Integer> rcol;

    @FXML
    private TextField id;

    @FXML
    private TableView<RecordData> recordTable;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<RecordData, Integer> ycol;

    private db.dbConnection connection;
    private ObservableList<RecordData> data;

    @FXML
    void add(ActionEvent event) {
        String sqlin = "INSERT INTO Records(ID,Name,Artist,Year,Genre,Price,Rating) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        try {
            Connection conn = connection.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sqlin);
            ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(this.id.getText()));
            ps.setString(2, this.name.getText());
            ps.setString(3, this.artist.getText());
            ps.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(this.year.getText()));
            ps.setString(5, this.genre.getText());
            ps.setDouble(6, Double.parseDouble(this.price.getText()));
            ps.setInt(7, Integer.parseInt(this.rating.getText()));
            ps.execute();
            conn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void clear(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void load(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            Connection conn = connection.getConnection();
            this.data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Records");
            while(rs.next()) {
                this.data.add(new RecordData(rs.getInt(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3),rs.getInt(4),rs.getString(5),rs.getDouble(6),rs.getInt(7)));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.idcol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<RecordData, Integer>("ID"));
        this.ncol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<RecordData, String>("Name"));
        this.acol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<RecordData, String>("Artist"));
        this.ycol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<RecordData, Integer>("Year"));
        this.gcol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<RecordData, String>("Genre"));
        this.pcol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<RecordData, Double>("Price"));
        this.rcol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<RecordData, Integer>("Rating"));

        this.recordTable.setItems(null);
        this.recordTable.setItems(this.data);
    }

    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb ) {
        this.connection = new dbConnection();
    }

}
```

And here is the recorddata class:

```
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class RecordData {

    private IntegerProperty ID;
    private StringProperty Name;
    private StringProperty Artist;
    private IntegerProperty Year;
    private StringProperty Genre;
    private DoubleProperty Price;
    private IntegerProperty Rating;

    public RecordData(int id, String name, String artist, int year, String genre, double price, int rating) {
        this.ID = new SimpleIntegerProperty(id);
        this.Name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.Artist = new SimpleStringProperty(artist);
        this.Year = new SimpleIntegerProperty(year);
        this.Genre = new SimpleStringProperty(genre);
        this.Price = new SimpleDoubleProperty(price);
        this.Rating = new SimpleIntegerProperty(rating);


    }

    public IntegerProperty getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(IntegerProperty iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }

    public StringProperty getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(StringProperty name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public StringProperty getArtist() {
        return Artist;
    }

    public void setArtist(StringProperty artist) {
        Artist = artist;
    }

    public IntegerProperty getYear() {
        return Year;
    }

    public void setYear(IntegerProperty year) {
        Year = year;
    }

    public StringProperty getGenre() {
        return Genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(StringProperty genre) {
        Genre = genre;
    }

    public DoubleProperty getPrice() {
        return Price;
    }

    public void setPrice(DoubleProperty price) {
        Price = price;
    }

    public IntegerProperty getRating() {
        return Rating;
    }

    public void setRating(IntegerProperty rating) {
        Rating = rating;
    }
```

If anyone knows how to get just the value and not the "IntegerProperty [Value: 1]" part, then please help me!

Comment: Perhaps you can post your `.fxml` file as well?

Comment: "I can retrieve the data" so please remove all database handling code and post [mre]. Hard code the test data.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way a `PropertyValueFactory` with `<name>` provided as constructor argument works is:

1. It tries to find a method `<name>Property()` in the item class returning an `ObservableValue`
2. If such a method is not found it tries to find a method `get<Name>()` and wraps the value returned in a property object

Since your `RecordData` class does not adhere to the conventions for javafx properties, the second alternative is used, but instead of getting the value that is supposed to be wrapped in an `ObservableValue` object, there returned objects are the properties themselfs which `PropertyValueFactory` proceeds to wrap in property objects resuling in `ObservableValue<StringProperty>`s and the like being returned, not `ObservableValue<String>` ect.

Providing getters and setters for the properties defies the purpose btw: They are useful to observe changes in value using listeners added via `addListener`. If you replace the whole property instead of assigning a new value, the listener won't be triggered.

Here's how the `year` property should be rewritten. Modify the other properties accordingly:

```
private final IntegerProperty year; // prevent accidental replacement and adhere to java naming conventions
...

public RecordData(int id, String name, String artist, int year, String genre, double price, int rating) {
    ...
    this.year = new SimpleIntegerProperty(year);
    ...
}

public int getYear() {
    return year.get();
}

public void setYear(int value) {
    year.set(value);
}

public IntegerProperty yearProperty() {
    return year;
}
```

```
this.ycol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<RecordData, Integer>("year"));
```

You could also replace the use of `PropertyValueFactory` with a lambda expression. This would allow the compiler to do some type checking:

```
this.ycol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().yearProperty());
```

Note that `IntegerProperty` is a `ObservableValue<Number>` not `ObservableValue<Integer>` requiring you to modify declaration of the column.

Comment: no, it's very suboptimal to use a PropertyValueFactory if the model exposes the property

Comment: @kleopatra The model exposes the property ***the wrong way*** as mentioned in the answer. Even using a custom implementation the code in the question will yield undesired results as soon as you call a setter... Thanks for downvoting because of your personal dislike of the `PropertyValueFactory` class btw.

Comment: yours is written correctly, afais or what am I missing? Nothing to do with personal dislike, it's the wrong thingy to do: it's error prone (as we see here several times daily), can't be detected at compile time and forces reflection where none is needed.

Comment: much love <3 @fabian

Comment: @kleopatra perhaps you could point us to an example that **does not** use `PropertyValueFactory` ? (thanks :-)

Comment: @Abra: pretty simple to create one: `this.ycol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().yearProperty());`